# web scraping in r (with loop)

Tags: r, loops, web, screen-scraping

I need to scrapes data from [this link](https://bra.areacodebase.com/number_type/M?page=0)  and save table in csv. What I have now: 
I can scrap using rvest the first page, second page and save these tables using this code:

```
library(rvest)
webpage <- read_html("https://bra.areacodebase.com/number_type/M?page=0")
data <- webpage %>%
  html_nodes("table") %>%
  .[[1]] %>% 
  html_table()
 url<- "https://bra.areacodebase.com/number_type/M?page=0"
webpage2<- html_session(url) %>% follow_link(css = ".pager-next a")
data2 <- webpage %>%
 html_nodes("table") %>%
 .[[1]] %>%
  html_table()
data_all <- rbind(data, data2)
write.table(data_all, "df_data.csv", sep = ";", na = "", quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)

#result<- lapply(webpage, %>% follow_link(css = ".pager-next a"))
#data_all <- rbind(data:data2)
```

However, I can't figure out how to run loop.

Comment: what do you mean by 'loops'?

Comment: to scrape all pages until page-5090. Now I can to scrap page to page.

Answer (score 4):

You can either go to the next link with `follow_link` or get the page via URL directly:

```
webpage <- "https://bra.areacodebase.com/number_type/M?page=0"

for(i in 2:5089) {
  data <- read_html(webpage) %>%
    html_nodes("table") %>%
    .[[1]] %>% 
    html_table()

  webpage <- html_session(webpage) %>% follow_link(css = ".pager-next a") %>% .[["url"]]
}
```

Or, with direct URL:

```
for(i in 0:5089) {
  webpage <- read_html(paste0("https://bra.areacodebase.com/number_type/M?page=", i))
  data <- webpage %>%
    html_nodes("table") %>%
    .[[1]] %>% 
    html_table()
}
```

Comment: if I use the first example i receive error "Error: is.character(url) is not TRUE." How i can fix this problem? thx.

Comment: Hi, how would you save the data separately for each i? I am working on a similar task and would like to save the data for each webpage in a separate datafile. When I use something like  `webpage[[i]] <-`  or  `data[[i]] <-` it does not work.

Comment: Writing the data into a dataframe and then ussing `assign` to add the iteration number to the data frame name seems to work for me.